# PHP: Why is this an infinite loop?

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, combinations, infinite-loop

```
$x = 0;
$y = 0;

while ($x < 6);
{
    while ($y < 6)
    {
    echo "INSERT INTO map_location(xLoc,yLoc) VALUES ($x,$y)"; 
    $y++;
    }
    $x++;
}
```

I am trying to generate SQL statements in a batch using a PHP script to generate all possible combinations of x,y coordinates from 0 to 6. That should be a total of 49 combinations, and I didn't want to insert them one by one. I am struggling to figure out why this is an infinite loop.

Comment: Remove the semicolon after the first while loop. That one line will loop endlessly, without going into the rest of the code at all.

Comment: Also, as written, your loops will stop when the variables are 5 - you should amend the check to `<= 6` if you want 7 iterations.

Comment: GAH, semi-colons again! Thanks andrewsi

Comment: Well, it also does not really deserve an upvote. So as this now has been fixed, this also leaves some reps plus for the OP and I think we can live with this, right?

Comment: The last iteration over the loop stops at 6 with the < operator, if I were to set it to <= it would include 7, which is undesirable. That is why I initialize both variables at 0 instead of 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for ($x=0;$x<=6;$x++)

    for ($y=0;$y<=6;$y++)

         echo "INSERT INTO map_location(xLoc,yLoc) VALUES ($x,$y) <br />";
```

Answer (score 5):

This statement:

```
while ($x < 6);
```

Is basically this:

```
while ($x < 6) { }
```

And that's an <strike>endless</strike> infinite loop.

Comment: Lets maintain the proper nomenclature :)  it's an `infinite loop`

Comment: @sircapsalot wish granted :)

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have a semi-colon after your first `while`, making it logically say,

```
$x = 0; 
while ( $x < 6 ); 
// the above statement is always going to be true because x = 0 (and 0 is less than 6), hence, always going to loop.
```

Remove the semi-colon and you should be set.